# Setup VPN for Linux in iran

Tags: linux, vpn

I have just installed Ubuntu 23.04
I live in iran so I need VPN for almost any thing
I have vpn for Linux like *** and **** but the problem is I need VPN for logging to my account in these VPNs.
Chrome VPN extensions are not going to help me because I only can login to my VPN account using terminal.

I want fast and simple solution.
I just need to have a VPN connection for 10 min so I can setup two VPNs I mentioned before.‌

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.